# How to integrate this exponential function?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I'm doing probability hw, and got stuck on the following integration:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty }e^{\frac{-(\ln(y))^2}{2}}dy$$

Any hint would be very appreciate!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: After the obvious change of variable, we are integrating $e^u e^{-u^2/2}=e^{-(u^2-2u)/2}$. Now complete the square.

Comment: thanks so much for the hint!!!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the change of variables $u=\ln y$ and then check Gaussian integrals.